# Formulaic representation of the lowest form of the denominator of a rational number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, rational-numbers

Given an arbitrary rational number $p$, is there a way to find out the denominator of its simplest form? In other words, can we formulaically (non-algorithmically) find the lowest integer denominator of all the ways $p$ can be represented?

Suppose $p$ = $\frac{n}{d}$ is the lowest form. Then, I am looking for an $f(x)$ such that $f(p)$ would have produced $d$. As an extension, can there also be a $g$ such that $g(p)$ would have been $n$?

I played around with inverses, proportions, and integer division, but I can't seem to figure out [1] if this can be done and if so, [2] how.

Comment: `Given an arbitrary rational number p` How are you "*given*" $\,p\,$? If it's as a ratio of two integers, then just cancel out the $\,\gcd\,$. Otherwise you'll need to elaborate some more on what the question really means to ask.

Comment: Assume that all you have is $p$ and the fact that $p\in\mathbb{Q}$. It's an attempt to generalize. The whole idea (hope) is that the lowest $n$ and $d$ should be expressible in terms of $p$, if they can have such an intuitive definition.

Comment: `the fact that p∈Q` How is that "*fact*" established? What is $\,p\,$, and in what form do you "*receive*" it?

Comment: As a parallel argument, do you feel a need to _prove_ that an arbitrary $n$ is actually a natural number every time you deal with natural numbers?

But to answer your question, $p$ is received as $p$ and the fact may be "told". Think of it as receiving a _pointer_ (using computer science terms) to a variable which you may remotely manipulate.

Comment: It's not about proving, it's about what the premises are. Your question appears to assume that $\,p\,$ is rational, which by definition means that it's the ratio of two integers, and in that case see my first comment - just cancel out the $\,\gcd\,$ between the numerator and the denominator. How *else* do you know that an arbitrary $\,p\,$ is rational, if you can't write it as the ratio of two integers, or don't know its decimal (repeating) representation, or ...? P.S. About the computer analogy, note that *all* computer numbers are rational, so the question doesn't make much sense as posed.

Comment: I suppose this is somewhat similar to what I meant.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2185930/is-haskell-style-pattern-matching-allowed-in-conventional-mathematics-and-if-not?rq=1

But I understand you point. However, consider that you knew $p=n/d$. What I'm trying to say is, is there a way to arrive at $d$ through symbolic manipulation, such as, using the basic arithmetic operators?

Comment: If you know $\,p = n' / d'\,$ for some integers $\,n', d'\,$, then it's trivial to derive the $\,n/d\,$ form with coprime $\,n,d\,$. If you don't know *any* representation of $\,p\,$ as a ratio of two integers, then you still need to clarify *what* you know about $\,p\,$ which makes you think it's a rational. About computers, note that even the so-called floating-point formats are internally stored as rationals with finitely many significant digts, which can be easily translated into a ratio-of-integers, depending on the particular format.

Comment: Any thoughts about the answers, Aalok?

Comment: I'm still trying to convince myself of your answer @GerryMyerson

Comment: Convince yourself that the algorithm works? or convince yourself that there's nothing better?

Answer (score 1):

There is no formula of the type that I think you want. There is a good algorithm. Namely, you let $a_0=[p]$, let $b_0=(p-a_0)^{-1}$, $a_i=[b_{i-1}]$, $b_i=(b_{i-1}-a_i)^{-1}$, continuing until $b_i$ blows up. You then have the continued fraction partial quotients $a_0,a_1,\dots,a_n$ for $p$, from which you reconstruct $p$ in lowest terms.

Comment: Easier: get the gcd and divide each part by that.

Comment: Get the gcd of ... of what, exactly? As near as I can figure, you're not given $p$ in the form $n/d$; you're just, in some not-quite-explained way, given $p$.

Comment: Ah. I see what you mean. What form would the rational number be given that does not have numerator or denominator?

Comment: @marty, that's the information dxiv tried to get out of OP in the comments on the question, but without much success. In my answer, I assume you're given the rational as a decimal approximation.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "no" because the whole point of rationals is that they're equal regardless of common factors and there's no way for anything to distinguish between them *on purpose* because that's just what we mean by "equal". Any means of distinguishing them would have to be an "algorithm" which operates on their parts and not a "formula" which operates on the numbers.